# in RStudio shiny, wishing to customize a table

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

In an RStudio shiny application with a table produced by `renderTable()`, I'd like to add a leading column of radio-buttons (reactive, of course) and change the style of the selected row. What's the best strategy?  I think I can use jQuery if absolutely necessary, but isn't there a simpler way? I've tried inserting html into table cells within the `renderTable()` expression args... doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pursuing @MadScone 's excellent advice, I came up with the following code,
which is the definitive solution to
Some additional features that make it work for me are:
* the radio buttons are in column 1 (not row 1)
* they belong to the same radio group
* the table header row is properly formatted
* the row selected by radio button receives special formatting, without needing jQuery.

```
values = reactiveValues(PopRow=1)   ### To receive and hold the selected row number.

f.objects_table_for_OneCT = function(){
    f.changeSelectedRow()        #### See definition below.
    df = createObjectsTable()    #### Any data frame goes here; code not provided here.
    selectedRow = values$PopRow
    header_html <- function(table_cell) paste0('<th>', table_cell, '</th>')
    cell_html <- function(table_cell) paste0('<td>', table_cell, '</td>')
    radio_html <- function(radio_name, radio_value, is_checked, radio_text) {
      paste0('<input type="radio" name="', 
             radio_name, '" value=', radio_value, 
                   ifelse(is_checked, " checked ", ""),
                   '>', radio_text)
    }    
    row_html <- function(table_row_num) {
      table_row = df[table_row_num, ]
      cells <- sapply(table_row, cell_html)
      cells <- c(cell_html(radio_html(
                  "whichRow", table_row_num, table_row_num == selectedRow, "")),
               cells)
      collapse_cells <- paste0(cells, collapse='')
      selectedRowStyle = "style='color:red; font-weight:bold'"
      collapse_cells <- paste0('<tr ', 
                     ifelse(table_row_num == selectedRow, selectedRowStyle, ""),
                    '>', collapse_cells, '</tr>')
      collapse_cells 
    }
    df_rows <- sapply(1:nrow(df), row_html) 
    df_header_row <- header_html(c("CHOICE", names(df)))
    collapse_cells <- paste0(c(df_header_row, df_rows), collapse='')    
    full_table <- paste0('<table class=\"data table table-bordered table-condensed\">', 
                         collapse_cells, '</table>')
    return(full_table)
  }

  output$objects_table_for_OneCT = renderText({f.objects_table_for_OneCT()})
```

(Concerning the last line, I habitually wrap my `expr` arg in a function, so I can `debug`. So far it's worked fine.)

The function that responds to the radio buttons is as follows:

```
  f.changeSelectedRow = reactive({
    if(is.null(values$PopRow)) values$PopRow = 1
    if(!is.null(input$whichRow))   ### from the radio button set.
             if(input$whichRow != values$PopRow) values$PopRow = input$whichRow
  })
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does the data source for df need to be reactive as well?

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer on this. Probably not, but it makes me sad to see it unanswered. I would just create the table html myself and use `renderText()`.

As an example, say you want this data frame on your page with radio buttons in the top row:

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=1:5)
```

We first need to turn `df` into a HTML table. Here's functions to make HTML table cells and rows:

```
cell_html <- function(table_cell) paste0('<td>', table_cell, '</td>')

row_html <- function(table_row) {
  cells <- sapply(table_row, cell_html)
  collapse_cells <- paste0(cells, collapse='')
  paste0('<tr>', collapse_cells, '</tr>')
}
```

And using those functions:

```
df_rows <- apply(df, 1, row_html)
```

Now here's a silly little function to make radio buttons:

```
radio_html <- function(radio_name, radio_value, radio_text) {
  paste0('<input type="radio" name="', 
   radio_name, '" value="', radio_value, '">', radio_text)
}
```

Let's make as many radio buttons as there are columns in `df`:

```
radios <- sapply(seq_along(df), 
  function(x) radio_html(paste0('row', x), x, paste(x)))
```

That will produce HTML of the form:

```
<input type="radio" name="row1" value="1">1
```

For each row. Then throw `radios` into `row_html` to make a HTML table row out of them:

```
radio_row <- row_html(radios)
```

Now we just need to combine `df`, the radio buttons and wrap the whole thing in HTML table tags.

```
table_cells <- c(radio_row, df_rows)
collapse_cells <- paste0(table_cells, collapse='')
full_table <- paste0('<table>', collapse_cells, '</table>')
```

Put this whole beast in a `renderText()` function. I'm not sure if you are using the `ui.R` or your own custom HTML interface. I always do the latter, it gives you a lot more freedom. I would have this on my page:

```
<div name="x" id="x" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
```

To render my table to `output$x`. To style your selected row I would recommend using jQuery. A simple event along the lines of (highly untested) [**EDIT: see suggested amendment in comments below**]:

```
$('table input:radio').change(function() {

  var index = $('#table input:radio').index(this);

  // Add one to skip radio button row.
  $('table tr').eq(index + 1).css('background-color', 'blue');

  // Also handle reset on other rows
  // ...
  // ...

});
```

You could alternatively try and build the table and a "selected" class to the appropriate table row server-side, with some CSS ready to style it.

In the absence of sample data, all of this is untested so expect some errors.

Also, if you are happy using `ui.R` rather than your own custom HTML, this method should still work. I just suggest using custom HTML as you seem to be wandering down that route.

---

I was answering what you asked... i.e. to make a leading row of radio buttons. I probably wouldn't do that myself though. Why not just produce your table as normal with `renderTable()` and add in the radio buttons separately, i.e. not part of the table at all? See [this page of the Shiny tutorial](http://rstudio.github.com/shiny/tutorial/#dynamic-ui) for help. If you absolutely have to line up the radio buttons with the table columns, this could be achieved with some CSSing.

Comment: Minor but important point, I'd change `$('table input:radio').change(function() {` to `$(document).on('change', 'table input:radio', function() {` as the latter will allow it to keep working after the table is re-created by the server (i.e. each time the `renderText` code executes). Basically it will listen for the change event on all future instances of `table input:radio`, not just the ones that exist at the time that line is executed.

Comment: Good point Joe, that's something that had been causing me trouble recently.