# User-interface using a table in shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I'm trying to make a user-interface based on a table in shiny. Each row of the table would consist of variable name and its parameters. I want to be able to click on the variable name, and a pop up or drop down window would display the distribution of the variable. Is there a function in shiny that could do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reactive input from renderDataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615723/reactive-input-from-renderdatatable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make responsive tables (so called DataTables) with the `renerDataTable()` function in server.R and the corresponding `dataTableOutput()` in ui.R built-in in Shiny

see: [Shiny renderDataTable Documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderDataTable.html) and [DataTables.net](http://datatables.net/)

As for the functionality where you want to display distributions when you hover over particular variables in your table, there's no such thing in shiny (for now). You'll need to use your JavaScript skills to accomplish that. Have a look at [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), a JavaScript Library that focuses on interactively visualizing data with JavaScript.

Comment: The functionality can be achieved with mouse over events and modal pop ups. Modal pop ups are available in the shinyBS package. The modal pop up can contain graphs etc see http://spark.rstudio.com/johnharrison/shinyBS-Demo/#tab-2709-10