# How to select only a single parent row in R Shiny js datatable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I have the first code chunk in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62836140/6170115) (reproduced below) and I want to extend it so that the user is able to select only a single parent row at a time.

There are two things I'm after:

1. the table should be all expanded in it's initial state. This means all child tables are expanded by default. The user can then collapse and expand as needed.
2. The user is only able to select and highlight a single parent row at a time. They should not be able to highlight multiple parent rows nor any child rows. What the user selects should be independent of whether or not that parent row is expanded.

```
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- ifelse(lengths(subdats), "&oplus;", "") 
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

df <- data.frame(
  COUNTRY = c("USA","Japan","USA","France","Italy","Canada","Japan"),
  NAME = c("Mark","Hue","Mary","Jean","Laura","John","Zhan"),
  AGE = c(20, 21, 18, 35, 40, 33, 27),
  DATE_OF_BIRTH = c("1980-05-01","1978-05-04","1983-11-01","1989-05-15","1985-08-08","1978-02-18","1983-09-27")
)

children <- lapply(split(df, df$COUNTRY), "[", -1)
dat0 <- data.frame(COUNTRY = names(children))

Dat <- NestedData(dat = dat0, children = unname(children))

library(DT)
## whether to show row names
rowNames = FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
## the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback <- JS(
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
  "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d !== null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ", 
  "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "    for(let key in data[0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
  "    return html;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- make the datatable --- //",
  "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
  "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
  "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
  "  });",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if(colNames.indexOf('_details') === -1){",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [", 
  "        {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "      ]",
  "    }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
  "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
  "var children = [];", 
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){", 
  "      // this child has not been created yet",
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      // this child has already been created",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});")

datatable(
  Dat, 
  callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
  options = list(
    paging = FALSE,
    searching = FALSE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        visible = FALSE, 
        targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx
      ),
      list(
        orderable = FALSE, 
        className = "details-control", 
        targets = colIdx
      ),
      list(
        className = "dt-center", 
        targets = "_all"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

This is so I can track that selected row to enable the user to click a button and perform other actions.

I've tried adding `'selection': single,` to the table options for the parent table but it allows multiple row selection and the child tables no longer display correctly.

I've also tried adding `selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'row+column')` in the table shown below but that allows multiple child rows/tables to be selected.

```
datatable(
  Dat, 
  callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
  selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'row+column'),
  options = list(
    paging = FALSE,
    searching = FALSE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        visible = FALSE, 
        targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx
      ),
      list(
        orderable = FALSE, 
        className = "details-control", 
        targets = colIdx
      ),
      list(
        className = "dt-center", 
        targets = "_all"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice request.

```r
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- ifelse(lengths(subdats), "&oplus;", "") 
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

df <- data.frame(
  COUNTRY = c("USA","Japan","USA","France","Italy","Canada","Japan"),
  NAME = c("Mark","Hue","Mary","Jean","Laura","John","Zhan"),
  AGE = c(20, 21, 18, 35, 40, 33, 27),
  DATE_OF_BIRTH = c("1980-05-01","1978-05-04","1983-11-01","1989-05-15","1985-08-08","1978-02-18","1983-09-27")
)

children <- lapply(split(df, df$COUNTRY), "[", -1)
dat0 <- data.frame(COUNTRY = names(children))

Dat <- NestedData(dat = dat0, children = unname(children))

library(DT)
## whether to show row names
rowNames = FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
## the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback <- JS(
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
  "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d !== null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ", 
  "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "    for(let key in data[0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
  "    return html;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- make the datatable --- //",
  "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
  "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
  "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
  "  });",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if(colNames.indexOf('_details') === -1){",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [", 
  "        {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "      ]",
  "    }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
  "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
  "var children = [];", 
  "var opened = -1;",
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(opened !== -1 && opened !== rowIdx) {",
  "    return false;",
  "  }",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()) {",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    opened = - 1;",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    opened = rowIdx;",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1) {", 
  "      // this child has not been created yet",
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      // this child has already been created",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});")

datatable(
  Dat, 
  callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
  options = list(
    paging = FALSE,
    searching = FALSE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        visible = FALSE, 
        targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx
      ),
      list(
        orderable = FALSE, 
        className = "details-control", 
        targets = colIdx
      ),
      list(
        className = "dt-center", 
        targets = "_all"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

I don't know why the headers of the child rows are misplaced. Maybe it's a problem of the browser I used (Edge).

---

## EDIT

Following your comment, here is the app you want:

```r
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- ifelse(lengths(subdats), "&oplus;", "") 
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

df <- data.frame(
  COUNTRY = c("USA","Japan","USA","France","Italy","Canada","Japan"),
  NAME = c("Mark","Hue","Mary","Jean","Laura","John","Zhan"),
  AGE = c(20, 21, 18, 35, 40, 33, 27),
  DATE_OF_BIRTH = c("1980-05-01","1978-05-04","1983-11-01","1989-05-15","1985-08-08","1978-02-18","1983-09-27")
)

children <- lapply(split(df, df$COUNTRY), "[", -1)
dat0 <- data.frame(COUNTRY = names(children))

Dat <- NestedData(dat = dat0, children = unname(children))

library(DT)
## whether to show row names
rowNames = FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
## the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback <- JS(
  "table.on('select', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {",
  "  if(type === 'row') {",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('selectedRow', indexes);",
  "  }",
  "});",
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {",
  "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1) {",
  "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
  "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d !== null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ", 
  "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "    for(let key in data[0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
  "    return html;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- make the datatable --- //",
  "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
  "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
  "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
  "  });",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if(colNames.indexOf('_details') === -1){",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [", 
  "        {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "      ]",
  "    }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
  "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
  "var children = [];", 
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()) {",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1) {", 
  "      // this child has not been created yet",
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      // this child has already been created",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});")


# shiny app ####
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("tbl"),
  br(),
  h3("Selected row:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selectedRow")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["tbl"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      Dat, 
      extensions = "Select", selection = "none",
      callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
      options = list(
        paging = FALSE,
        searching = FALSE,
        select = list(
          style = "single", selector = "td:not(:first-child)"
        ),
        columnDefs = list(
          list(
            visible = FALSE, 
            targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx
          ),
          list(
            orderable = FALSE, 
            className = "details-control", 
            targets = colIdx
          ),
          list(
            className = "dt-center", 
            targets = "_all"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  output[["selectedRow"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["selectedRow"]] + 1
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that the selected row is in `input[["selectedRow"]] + 1`.

[image]

Comment: The OG himself :) That wasn't exactly what I meant. I added extra clarification to my question but I want multiple parent rows to be expandable but the user can only actually select and highlight a single parent row at a time. Then I'm going to use `selected <- input$data_table_rows_selected` like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67523080/6170115

Comment: @happyspace Ok. See my edit.