# Radio Buttons as part of a table

Tags: r, shiny

Once again, I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

I'm trying to put into a shiny application a user interface that has radio buttons in the left most column of a table.  Selecting a button would determine which data gets used in subsequent analyses.

So far I've managed to get the radio buttons in the table based on the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512510/in-rstudio-shiny-wishing-to-customize-a-table), but I can't seem to get the reactive values corresponding to the input to change when I choose a different radio button.

Some guidance on what I'm missing would be much appreciated.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Radio Matrix"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(  ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title = "Selection",
          br(),
          uiOutput("table"),
          verbatimTextOutput("gear"),
          verbatimTextOutput("reactive_gear")
        )
      )
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(gear = 3)

  output$table <- 
    renderText({
      f.changeSelectedRow()
      "<!--html_preserve--><table style = 'border-collapse:collapse;'>
      <tr>
        <th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''></th>\n
        <th colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style=''>gear</th></tr>\n\n
      <tr>
        <td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='text-align:center;background-color:#DCDCDC;'><input type='radio' name='gear' value='3 checked = 'checked> </td>\n
        <td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='text-align:center;background-color:#DCDCDC;'>3</td></tr>\n\n
      <tr>
        <td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='text-align:center;background-color:#F5F5F5;'><input type='radio' name='gear' value='4 checked = '> </td>\n
        <td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='text-align:center;background-color:#F5F5F5;'>4</td></tr>\n\n
      <tr>
        <td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='text-align:center;background-color:#DCDCDC;'><input type='radio' name='gear' value='5 checked = '> </td>\n
        <td colspan = '1'; rowspan = '1'; style='text-align:center;background-color:#DCDCDC;'>5</td></tr>\n
      </table><br/><br/>\n<!--/html_preserve-->"
    })

  f.changeSelectedRow = reactive({
    if(is.null(values$gear)) values$gear <- 3
    if(!is.null(input$gear))   ### from the radio button set.
             if(input$gear != values$gear) values$gear <- input$gear
  })

  output$gear <- renderText(input$gear)
  output$reactive_gear <- renderText(values$gear)

})
```

The table returned to `output$table` is produced by a series of functions eventually outputting HTML code as a character string.  I've provided only a simplified version of the HTML code hard coded into `renderText` as I suspect the HTML code isn't the problem (though I'm okay with being wrong).

The function I used to generate the radio button code is:

```
radio_html <- function(inputId, label, choices, selected=NULL) {
  if (is.null(selected)) selected <- choices[1]

  paste0("<input type='radio' name='", 
         inputId, "' value='", choices,
         " checked = '",
         ifelse(choices == selected, "checked", ""),
         "> ", label)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the HTML output for `?radioButtons` you need to tell shiny to react to these values by wrapping them in

```
<div id='gear' class='form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container'>
      <div class='shiny-options-group'>
      <!-- HTML here -->
      </div>
</div>
```

Also you need to set the class of the inputs to `shiny-bound-input`, here's a quick example to custom HTML that shiny reacts to:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Radio Matrix"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(  ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title = "Selection",
                 br(),
                 uiOutput("table"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("gear"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("reactive_gear")
        )
      )
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$table <- 
    renderText({
      '
      <div id="dist" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container">
      <label class="control-label" for="dist">Distribution type:</label>
      <div class="shiny-options-group">
      <div class="radio">
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="dist" value="norm" checked="checked"/>
      <span>Normal</span>
      </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="dist" value="unif"/>
      <span>Uniform</span>
      </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="dist" value="lnorm"/>
      <span>Log-normal</span>
      </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
      <label>
      <input type="radio" name="dist" value="exp"/>
      <span>Exponential</span>
      </label>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div> 
      '
    })

  output$reactive_gear <- renderText(input$dist)

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Also check that you have the right amount of quotes, I think your missing some in your radio_html function. Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic!  I think that's twice you've bailed me out this week.  I've managed to incorporate this into a couple of functions to facilitate the process, which I'll post shortly.

Comment: Glad to hear it and as always glad I can help! I've tried building shiny UI's pure HTML as opposed to in R and from my limited experience it really helps to create the element you want to code in HTML in R first so you can view how to setup the HTML (or go to the shiny gallery and right click -> inspect elements).

Answer (score 1):

All the credit for this answer goes to Oskar.  After studying his example, I have managed to work out a pair of functions that can be used together to get the desired look.

This requires a development version package to generate the html code for the formatted table, but it's a generalizable process of

1. Create a data frame
2. Add a column of radio buttons with `radio_html`
3. Convert your data frame to an HTML table
4. Run that html code into `radio_table`.  Make sure the `inputId` arguments to `radio_html` and `radio_table` are equal.

---

```
devtools::install_github("nutterb/pixiedust")
library(pixiedust)
library(shiny)

#* Generate a vector of radio buttons to include in a data frame
radio_html <- function(inputId, label, choices, selected=NULL) {
  if (is.null(selected)) selected <- choices[1]

  paste0("<input class='radio' type='radio' name='", 
         inputId, "' value='", choices,
         "' checked = '",
         ifelse(choices == selected, "checked", ""),
         "'> ", label)
}

#* Generate the tags around the table that allow the radio buttons to react
radio_table <- function(table_code, inputId, label){
  paste0("<div id='", inputId, "' class='form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container'>",
         "  <label class='control-label' for='", inputId, "'>", label, "</label>",
         "  <div class='shiny-options-group'>",
         table_code,
         "  </div>",
         "</div>")
}


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$table <- 
    renderText({
      DF <- data.frame(dist = c("Normal", "Uniform", "Lognormal", "Exponential"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

      DF$button <- radio_html(inputId = "dist",
                              label = "",
                              choices = c("norm", "unif", "lognorm", "exp"))

      #* This is mostly formatting fluff
      dust(DF[, 2:1], format = "html") %>%
        sprinkle_colnames("", "") %>%
        sprinkle(border = "all",
                 border_color = "#A9A9A9",
                 bg_pattern = c("#DCDCDC", "#F5F5F5"),
                 bg_pattern_by = "rows") %>%
        sprinkle_print_method("html") %>%
        print(asis = FALSE) %>%
        radio_table("dist", "Distribution")
    })


  output$dist <- renderText(input$dist)

})


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Radio Matrix"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(  ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title = "Selection",
                 br(),
                 uiOutput("table"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("dist")
        )
      )
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```